# How to gain Root access without typing sudo

Tags: debian, root, sudo, usergroups

I am using debian. I am trying to create a user called "admin" who has root access at login, ie, so that I do not have to type 'su' or 'sudo' before very command.
I realise the security implications of this.
Here are the changes I have made.

```html
$ cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
admin:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/admin:/bin/bash


$ cat /etc/group
root:x:0:admin
sudo:x:27:admin
admin:x:1001:


$ id
uid=1001(admin) gid=1001(admin) groups=1001(admin),0(root),27(sudo)

$ ifconfig
-bash: ifconfig: command not found

$ whoami
admin
```

Answer (score 1):

The key property for a Unix process to *be root* is having a uid of "0" (zero). In order to have a user that *will be root* when logged in, such user must be assigned zero as uid with the password file. For this your password file should read:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
admin:x:0:1001:,,,:/home/admin:/bin/bash
```

However, it is highly debatable whether it would make sense having a user different from *root* to be a *root login* user. If at all, you might use original *root* for login purposes. Having a different name is *security by obscurity* at best. Any measures for protecting a bad or fraudulent login using such user will apply to a user named *root* the same as to a user named any different.

The only potential benefit of having several *uid zero* users is:
You do have an independent set of passwords handed out to individuals that can be revoked individually.

So, if you are going to allow *root login* via whatever account you are going to use, then why not use *root* user in the first place?

For avoiding *to have to use sudo*:
With modern window systems and availability of tools like *screen* or *tmux*, it should be quite a low burden to start a *uid zero* shell in a separate window and perform actions requiring root permissions from there.